# Azure managed disk from source blob (vhd) is not modified (updated)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I am a bit confused with the Azure managed data disk (in ARM) created from VHDs stored in storage source blob. I have a script that creates snapshots on all the storage blobs, but for some reason the changes that are made on the managed disks are not applied to the VHDs.

So the previous dependencies were like:

```
storage blob -> container -> VHDs -> VMs
```

Currently:

```
storage blob -> container -> VHDs -> managed data disks -> VMs
```

I also have made sure when the VMs were created to use additional data disks, which were created from the existing VHDs. Any ideas about the synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

> but for some reason the changes that are made on the managed disks
>   are not applied to the VHDs.

If you create snapshot of **managed disk**, you can find snapshot via Azure portal, like this:
[image]

But if you create snapshot of VHDs(**unmanaged disk**), the snapshot will **not** show in Azure portal, you should use Azure PowerShell to list it:

```
$rg = "Your_resource_group_name"
$saname = "Your_storage_account_name"
$con = "vhds"
$keylist = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RG -StorageAccountName $saname
$Key = $Keylist[0].Value
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAname -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob *.vhd -Container $Con -Context $Ctx
```

Output like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes I understand that part and the script, the problem that I am currently facing is not the visibility of the snapshot, but when I use the snapshot that are most recently created, create disks from them and attach them to a different VM, the data is older.

Comment: The setup is the following: 1.VM with disk created from VHDs from source blob, 2. Another VM used to validated the snapshots of the blob storage that are used in the 1st VM.

Comment: The data in 2nd VM with disks created from the latest snapshots is not the same as the data in the 1st VM.

Comment: @badc0re snapshot for unmanaged disk? you want to use the newest snaoshot to create new VM?

Comment: @badc0re Have you select the right time and copy it to your storage account?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to reply, we changed the setup on the machine now, the current setup is to use only managed disk without source blob.

Comment: @badc0re OK, it seems managed disk works for you. Please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a managed disk from your own VHD blob your blob is copied to create the managed disk's blob in a different account. The managed disk does not even exist in your account, so taking snapshots of the original blob won't show any updates. You could even delete the original VHD blob and the managed disk will still exist.

If you want to create another VM with a copy of the modified managed disk you need to create a managed snapshot of that disk and use that managed snapshot as a source for your next VM.